# Flash AS2 using getUrl to POST variables?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-2

I have been tyring to figure this out for a while now and no luck.  I have some AS2 code below which works:

```
on(release)
{
    var sendText = "../Flash/uploadVoteandFeed.php?"; 

    sendText += "B=" + _root.JudgeBtext;
    sendText += "&C=" + _root.JudgeCtext;
    sendText += "&D=" + _root.JudgeDtext;
    sendText += "&vote=";
    if(_root.NowJudging == 'B') sendText += 2;
    if(_root.NowJudging == 'C') sendText += 3;
    if(_root.NowJudging == 'D') sendText += 4;

    getURL(sendText, "_self");

    stop;

}
```

As I said, this code IS WORKING.  But I would liek to modify to send "sendText" as post variables.  I just don't like seeing the extralong url with all the variables in it.  AS2 should be able to send this as a post var right?  I need the flash to open up "uploadVoteandFeed.php" on release in the same window/page, in order to show the user that their vote and feedback was successful and do other things with PHP at that point. (this is currently working with:)
    getURL(sendText, "_self");

But like I sadi I get a huge ugly URL and I just think it looks unprofessional.  the sendText variable string can end up being almost 264 chars, whcih is also the limit for URLs if I remeber correctly.  From everything I've read, AS2 should be able to do what I want, but I cant seem to figure it out.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify method in a getURL call:

```
getURL(url, "_self", "POST");
```

If I remember it right (haven't done AS2 in a while) it will send all variables that are defined in the current scope, so you could try something like this:

```
on(release)
{
   var B = _root.JudgeBtext;
   var C = _root.JudgeCtext;
   var D = _root.JudgeDtext;
   var vote = 1 // TODO: the check of _root.NowJudging

   getURL("../Flash/uploadVoteandFeed.php", "_self", "POST");

   stop;
}
```

See the documentation here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00000564.html

Comment: Thanks, Lars! This worked great!  Just to clarify for anyone else who sees this thread, using getURL in this manner seems to only upload the flash variables inside the on(release) statement.  I probably have about 20 other variables in my flash movie, but only sendText got posted.  Actually I kind of wonder how flash knew only to post that varaibale and none of the others since there is no reference to any variables at all in the new getURL() statement.